# Converting CSV file structure using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to create a PHP function where I can upload one CSV file into MySQL and then export another CSV file with certain changes in data and tables.

Example

> **CSV-1:**
>
> Table name = Photolink
>
> Table content = http:// www.sitename.com/image1.jpg

Convert it to:

> **CSV-2:**
>
> Table name = img_URL
>
> Table content = product/image1.jpg

I need your help in modifying the code to make this work;

I tried this code still it do not work, friends can u help me fix it please!

```
        $data1 = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, model, quantity, image_url) VALUES (:name, :model, :quantity, :image_url)");
    $data1->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $data1->bindParam(':model', $model);
    $data1->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
    $data1->bindParam(':image_url', $image_url);



    if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

        //get the csv file
        $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
        $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")) {
        if ($data[0]) {

        $name = $data[0];
        $model = $data[1];
        $quantity = 100;
        $image_url = $data[2];
        $data1->execute();

        }
    }
```

Comment: first you stop using addslashes(). it is absolutely pathetically useless GARBAGE and should not even exist. then you stop using the mysql_*() functions and switch to PDO or mysqli. Then you go read the PHP docs about loops and learn why your do() loop will NEVER work as written.

Comment: And you should stop using not quoted strings until they are constants names :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip your loop around:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")) {
    if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, model, quantity, image_url) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                //quantity is 100 for all
                '100',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."'
            )
        ");
    }
}
```

Because in your original code, `$data` doesn't even exist yet until you define it in the `while` statement.

There are many other issues, but this should get you going.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I tried your code still not data inserted in mysql ... can u guide me a little more please .... this is the first time i am trying to do this and have no idea

Comment: Switch to prepared statements with PDO, then we'll talk. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: thanks alot my friend, i will study the link and hope this would solve the issue :)

Comment: Dear joe, I tried this code still it do not work, friends can u help me fix it please! ---> codes updated in question

Comment: Much better. Move the calls to `bind_param` to inside the loop, before the call to `execute`

Comment: can u explain it a bit please :)